# Ways to share constants between applications written in Ruby and C?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, c, ruby

Hello Stackoverflowians -

I'm working with an embedded system that's written in C that communicates over a cell modem to a server written in Ruby on Rails. There message format is fairly simplistic and uses several constants to define messages types.

Right now, the ruby side of things takes the C include file, and scans for the constant definitions, and imports those via const_set.

Is there a better way to keep the ruby side sync'ed up with the C side of this project?

Thanks,

-- Mike

Answer (score 0):

Since you're comfortable with C, my suggestion would be to create a Ruby extension in C that uses the header from the C application to expose the constants. That way you're not stuck to declaring the constants in a specific way or custom parsing routines.

See [guides.rubygems.org](http://guides.rubygems.org/gems-with-extensions/) for a concise introduction to the topic.